# Calculate chinese new year date

Tags: php, datetime, intldateformatter

I want to find out the Chinese New Year date for a specific year using PHP. For the year 2022 I expect February 1st, 2022.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do with the [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.intldateformatter.php).

```
$year = 2022;
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'zh-CN@calendar=chinese',
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'Europe/Berlin',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL
);
$timeStamp = $formatter->parse($year.'/01/01');
$dateTime = date_create()->setTimeStamp($timeStamp);
echo $dateTime->format('j F Y');  //1 February 2022
```

Try it yourself with [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Fi1jL).